# Работа с текстом и иконками-маркерами в списке с Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap, li

Подскажите, делаю тестовый проект работая на Bootstrap 5, столкнулся с проблемой, которую никак не могу решить, надеюсь подскажите в какую сторону нужна думать - пробовал разные варианты, но совсем не помогло, не понимаю как это делается.
Прилагаю скриншот. Проблема в переносе текста, при создании списка большой текст переносится в нём с большими интервалами. Иконки и текст находятся внутри списка, т.к. не знаю как иначе выравнивать их, так проще всего вроде как, но проблема с текстом тогда.
Код html такой:

```
<li class="mb-1"><img class="icon me-2" src="./Image/Icon/Sqok.svg" alt="icon">Мы согласовываем с Вами эскиз и все нюансы;</li>
```

Класс icon задаёт иконке просто размеры:

```
.icon {
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px;
}
```

Куда думать?

[image: i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы советовал Вам иконки пунктов реализовать через псевдоэлемент, скажем, `before` элемента `li`. Потом Вас будет проще управлять этим через CSS. То есть, Вы сам элемент списка `li` позиционируете относительно через `position: relative;`, а его псевдоэлемент позиционируете абсоютно с левой стороны. Самому элементу  `li` нужно будет придать некий внутренний отступ слева `padding-left`, чтобы избежать наложение Вашей иконки поверх текста.

Например, при такой разметке:

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="mb-1">Мы обговариваем с Вами все детали: тематику, стиль и сюжет портрета;</li>
        <li class="mb-1">Вы вносите предоплату в размере 30% от стоимости шаржа;</li>
        <li class="mb-1">Я создаю предварительный эскиз;</li>
        <li class="mb-1">Мы согласовываем с Вами эскиз и все нюансы;</li>
    </ul>
```

я использовал следующие стили:

```
.mb-1 {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px; // здесь регулируется расстояние между иконкой и текстом
}

.mb-1::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block; // это нужно, чтобы можно было управлять шириной и высотой элемента
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: url([= здесь Ваш путь к иконке =]) 0 0 /cover no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; // этими значениями выставляйте иконку относительно элемента списка
    top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Невероятно! Я бы сам наверное никогда не пришёл к такому, т. к. пока ещё первые шаги в web. Спасибо огромное за Вашу помощь и разъяснения =)

Comment: Я раньше тоже думал точно так же, но YouTube творит чудеса)) Успехов Вам в этом деле! Рад, что смог помочь